# Multiple Rewrite conditions and rules for custom paths

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond, codeigniter

At the moment I have…

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|fonts|jw|mail|uploads|user_guide) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, I want to be able to rewrite a url like `/page/about/` similarly so it is actually 
`/index.php/page/id/about`

How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

(I actually did this once before and then killed my htaccess file and couldn't remember how I did it in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I've fixed it with

```
RewriteCond $1 ^page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/page/id/$1
```

And then from there extracted the page name/id.